# CSS to replace Parent + Label

Tags: html, css

I have a requirement in which i am having autogenerated code from a framework.

now my generated HTML is as below for each radio button:

```
<span class="af_selectOneRadio_content-input">
<input type="radio" name="pt1:r1:0:sor1" id="pt1:r1:0:sor1:_1" value="1" class="af_selectOneRadio_native-input" onclick="this.focus()">
</span>
<label for="pt1:r1:0:sor1:_1" class="af_selectOneRadio_item-text">Weekends</label>
```

Now I want to replace my radio button with an image of green dot and the unchecked ones with red dot.

The problem is that all forums show code when the label and the radio are adjescent but not in case when a span is enveloping the input type.

Please can anyone suggest how to handle this..??

how can i replace the radio button with an image. Also in case of selection, i need the label text to become bold too.

I am trying to do this without javascript as i have already tried that solution

Comment: There is no parent selector in css

Comment: With JavaScript it would be easy (with or without a library), with css it's impossible.